# How to replace the hardcoded data in views, stored procedures, and functions via a script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have some views and stored procedures which have some data hard-coded in their definitions.

```
CASE WHEN sprLatestSPR2.StatusID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20)
```

I create a table that holds all global variables. For example, I define `STATUS_SET1 to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20` in the table.

Now I need to write a script to replace all hard-coded data in the definitions of views & store procedures with queries. For example I need replace above clause with

```
CASE WHEN sprLatestSPR2.StatusID IN (SELECT STATUS_SET1 FROM myGlobalVariables)
```

How do I write a script to search the definitions of the views & stored procedures and do the replacement?

Update:

I have the query to find out the first part of my question, search the definition of view/store procedure for a specific sentence.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%StatusID<21%'
```

Now my question is how to update view/store procedure to replace all the occurrences of `StatusID<21` with some global variable?

New Update:

I run following script in the SSMS,

SELECT Name 
    FROM sys.procedures 
    WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%V.EmailStatus=''GP''%'

SELECT STUFF(REPLACE(definition, 'V.EmailStatus=''GP''', 'V.EmailStatus=''RL'''), 1, 6, 'ALTER')
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' 
FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%V.EmailStatus=''GP''%'

SELECT Name 
    FROM sys.procedures 
    WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%V.EmailStatus=''GP''%'

I got the same result from the third SELECT as the first SELECT, which is should be nothing, since I replaced GP with RL.

Comment: I find your problem interesting, but your question seems too complex. It asks for too many things at once. You'll need to know how to: get the definition of an object; search for a substring and replace it with another; save the modified definition on the server (update the object) – and do all all that programmatically, of course. Finally, you'll need to put all those steps (and maybe some others I failed to mention) together somehow. Try searching this site for partial answers first, then, if you are still struggling, get back and ask about the part that seems particularly difficult to you.

Comment: And please be most specific: what you've got, what you've tried etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the procedure starts with `CREATE` exactly, you can say:

```
SELECT STUFF(REPLACE(definition, '1, 2, ...', 'SELECT ...'), 1, 6, 'ALTER') 
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO'
FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%(1, 2, ...')%';
```

If it can have leading spaces, comments before `CREATE`, etc. then it can get a bit more complex.

You can also just return the scripts themselves, or script them out to files, then do your own search and replace within SSMS or your favorite text editor.

**EDIT** note that this will just produce the script to alter your objects. You'll want to verify them, backup your database first, then copy the script and run it.

**EDIT 2** explaining code based on question

`sys.sql_modules.definition` contains a `CREATE` script that represents your procedure/function body. It does not include the `GO` required between altering modules, nor is there a way to have it output an `ALTER` command instead (I've [asked for it in the past](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=273938) but I'll have to agree with them I'd rather see [`CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace)).

`STUFF` in this case takes the output (which will be `CREATE PROCEDURE ...` after the `1, 2, ...` has been replaced) and, starting with the first character, replaces the first 6 characters (`CREATE`) with `ALTER` - since the assumption is that you will want to run these as alters as opposed to drop / create (so that you don't lose permissions / dependencies).

The `GO` adds a batch separator between each body, since `ALTER PROCEDURE` must be in its own batch. So instead of...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bar
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

...which will generate errors, you'll have...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bar
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
GO
```

...which will ensure that each stored procedure is handled in its own batch.

Comment: Why not do REPLACE(REPLACE(definition, '1, 2, ...', 'SELECT ...'), 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')? CREATE PROCEDURE should only be in the definition once. 

You could also limit on only stored proc types for one run and functions for another (replacing PROCEDURE with FUNCTION) or do another replace to handle if you found CREATE FUNCTION instead.

Lastly, wouldn't you want to insert this into a temporary table and then run through it doing "exec sp_executesql" with your new alters? I didn't think you could actually modify the system definition yourself.

Comment: @Jeremy, yes, you could use an additional replace, but I personally prefer stuff. Especially because you can now handle both functions and procedures in one shot. I hope it was implied that this would just generate the scripts - you still have to backup your database first, verify them and run them, etc. I'll add that to the answer since it is apparently not clear.

Comment: I understand this part, REPLACE(definition, '1, 2, ...', 'SELECT ...'). But no quite sure about  STUFF(..., 1, 6, 'ALTER')      + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO', do u mind explaining that to me?

Comment: @GaolaiPeng I've updated my answer and hopefully have answered your questions.

Comment: Hey Can you check my update. I tried on some of my store-procedure, didn't work.

Comment: I copied your stored procedure and ran the script and the output seemed correct. Did you then copy the ALTER script to the top pane and run it? The code I posted just creates the script that you need to then run manually. I didn't put in the code to execute it because you should be validating it manually before you run it.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't notice that. How do I copy the modified store procedure back to the original one in the script?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want the original stored procedure in your script, run the query without the stuff / replace. `SELECT definition + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE ...`

Comment: After I run SELECT STUFF(REPLACE(definition... I can see the change in the result window in SSMS, but when I open my store procedure, it wasn't changed.

Comment: That's because the script I gave you just produces the ALTER script. If you want to actually RUN the alter script (required to actually implement a change), after you've reviewed the output, copy and paste it to a new query editor window, and run it there.

Comment: You cannot do the modification on the original store procedure and keep its format?

Comment: You can't just run a replace against sys.sql_modules because it's a catalog view and you can't update it (or the system table behind the scenes that it represents). This is the same reason you use sp_rename to rename a table or column, instead of an update against sys.objects or sys.columns. You can't update those system objects directly.

Comment: Then there is not so much help to write a script to modify sys.sql_modules, since I have to manually copy the altered definition back.  I might as well just manually do the modification.

Comment: There got be a way to do string replacement in store procedures/views....What if a user want to change the column name of a table, does the DBA has to go through all the store procedures/views... to manually modify all the references to the column name? It will be like recreate the DB.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my script, and that's too bad. The whole point was that you can script out a bunch of stored procedures and alter them in one go, using simple search & replace. If you don't think this is less work than manually right-clicking stored procedures in Object Explorer, then do that and have fun with it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just repeat this and see if I understood everything correctly:

- you have some SPs with hard-coded values
- you are asking for a script to replace these hard-coded values with new hard-coded values
- you want to do the replacing stuff every time you need new hard-coded values

Correct?
If yes, I wouldn't do it like that.

Instead, I would change the SPs and views once, so that the list of numbers comes from a settings table.

The settings table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StatusSets](
    [StatusSetID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StatusSets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StatusSetID] ASC,
    [StatusID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Some sample data:

```
insert into StatusSets values (1, 1)
insert into StatusSets values (1, 2)
insert into StatusSets values (1, 3)
insert into StatusSets values (1, 4)
```

Then, you can change your SPs and views like this:
(I assume that your main table where you select from is called `Status`)

```
create view vLoadStatus as
select StatusSets.StatusSetID, Status.*
from Status
inner join StatusSets on Status.StatusID = StatusSets.StatusID
```

and:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLoadStatus]
    @StatusSetID int
AS
BEGIN

    select *
    from Status
    where StatusID in
    (
        select StatusID from StatusSets where StatusSetID = @StatusSetID
    )

END
```

Now you can call the view and SP:

```
exec spLoadStatus 1

select * from vLoadStatus where StatusSetID = 1
```

In the future, when you want to run the SPs and views with different settings, you just need to insert the new settings with a new `StatusSetID` in the `StatusSets` table and pass that `StatusSetID` to the SPs and views.

Comment: Actually this is just what the OP's intention is, i.e. replacing hard-coded values with table references (*not* with other hard-coded values). The question seems to be how to change all the relevant objects using a (single) script (in particular, how to save the new definition programmatically). Anyway, you've done a great job confirming the OP's intention to be a good idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to script out `alter` statements for each module. SQL Server 2005 and higher does not allow ad hoc updates to the system objects.

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/249db627-80d3-4129-b4c1-90e929338d7c

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest:

1) Build a registry or global variables table, where for each case of this you store your IN clause filters in a comma delimited string.

2) Install this [function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) on your database.

3) In the query, create a temporary data set by splitting that specific string then inner join to only show records with those values.

```
SELECT  tblA.col1,
    tblA.col2,
    tblA.col3

FROM TableA tblA
INNER JOIN (    SELECT A.Item
            FROM registry 
            CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(RegValue,',') A
            WHERE RegId = 1 ) tblB

ON tblA.JoinCol = tblB.Item
```